# Flash - Page tear animation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Can anyone recommend a decent tutorial, add-on or approach to creating a page rip off effect in flash?

I want to create a notepad where each page can be ripped off to reveal further content.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for a [pageFlip](http://pageflip.hu/) with a tearing feature? if so it does exist even though I can't find the link (anyway it was AS2).

if you want more flexibility, you can take a look at a cloth simulation ; [derschmale did a great example](http://www.derschmale.com/demo/cloth2D/Cloth2D.html) and [pixelero did sort of the same with linked lists (=faster)](http://pixelero.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/linkedgrid/)

there's also this particle physics engine called [Traer](http://blog.sqrtof5.com/?p=53) that have been ported from java and that allows you to get the [cloth behaviour](http://blog.sqrtof5.com/?p=44) with fewer lines of code and some fine tuning (stiffness, damping a.s.o. ).

the general idea is to subdivide the displayObject you want to tear off into a series of triangles, take a snapshot of that object in a BitmapData, then redraw the distorted grid with the drawTriangles() method. 
I think it is how they do the thing in the cloth examples.

Comment: cheers for that, the cloth transition looks interesting, though the pageflip rip off would be ideal for a quick fix, i'll try and find it somewhere!

Comment: http://www.actionscript.org/showMovie.php?id=1248 (page 11 of the sample ) is what I was thinking of :)